# SAP DS: Read input xml file result in an error

Tags: sap-data-services

I am using SAP Data Services v. 4.2.

I am trying to acquire an XML file in input.

I created a new XML Schema starting from a .xsd file.

When I launch the job I have this error:

> 2076818752FIL-0522267/25/2017 2:56:35 PM|Data flow DF_FE_XXXX
>
> 2076818752FIL-0522267/25/2017 2:56:35 PMREAD MESSAGE XX_INPUT_FILE OUTPUT(XX_INPUT_FILE)> cannot find file location object <%1> in repository.
>
> 24736 20092   RUN-050304  7/26/2017 9:18:39 AM    Function call <raise_exception ( Error 52226 gestito in Error_handling ) > failed, due to error <50316>

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

problem in the way how you identify file location in `Data File(s)` section of your format, `BODS` thinks that you provide some `File Location` and it don't find such

for more information about ["File Locations"](https://help.sap.com/viewer/e54136ab6a4a43e6a370265bf0a2d744/4.2.10/en-US/3f5bd65acf0e43638b4e983bb9fe46f8.html)